# For each loop through API values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm having trouble finding the correct way to list out all of my data here is my setup. `@product.pic_url` will return 5 images but only shows the first one how would I iterate through them all?

**product.rb**

```
class TaobaoProduct
  attr_reader :desc,
              :approve_status,
              :title,
              :item_url,
              :nick,
              :num_iid,
              :pict_url,
              :pic_url,
              :title,
              :volume,
              :zk_final_price,
              :reserve_price,
              :price,
              :detail_url,
              :cid

  attr_writer :title

  def initialize(product)
    product.each { |name, value| instance_variable_set("@#{name}", value) }
  end

  # function to get individual taobao product
  # product_id: Taobao product id
  def self.find(product_id)
    tb_hash = OpenTaobao.get(
      :method => 'taobao.item.get',
      :fields => 'num_iid,title,nick,desc,pic_url',
      :num_iid => product_id
    )
    new(tb_hash["item_get_response"]["item"])
  end
end
```

**product.haml**

```
.container
  .row
    .col-xs-12
      %h1= @product.title

  .row
    .product-v2.col-md-9
      .row
        .col-md-6.col-xs-12
          %img{:src => "#{@product.pic_url}" + "_400x400.jpg"}
        .col-md-6.col-xs-12
          .price-v2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Product#pic_url` actually returns an array of image urls, you could do something like this:

```
.container
  .row
    .col-xs-12
      %h1= @product.title

  .row
    .product-v2.col-md-9
      .row
        .col-md-6.col-xs-12
          - @product.pic_url.each do |url| 
            %img{:src => "#{url}_400x400.jpg"}
        .col-md-6.col-xs-12
          .price-v2
```

Comment: That's actually what i tried earlier but I cant ever get passed this error `undefined method each for #<String:0x007f71583350d8>`

Comment: Per that error message, pic-url isn't an array, it's a string. If the string contains multiple URLs, then you'll need to extract them via split or something similar. Otherwise, you'll need to figure out why pic-url isn't an array and fix that - then this code should work.

Comment: Ahh alright, That makes since ill see if I can figure it out